# left shift with or

Tags: c

```
i2c_receiveData(sDevice *psDevice, byte_t *pbBuffer, uint16_t *puiLen)
{
.
.    
//extract the packet data length
unFrameLen = (*(pbBuffer+1) << 8) | *(pbBuffer + 2);
if(unFrameLen > *puiLen)
unFrameLen=*puiLen;
.
.
}
```

Here how this statement is finding Frame Length?

**unFrameLen = (*(pbBuffer+1) << 8) | *(pbBuffer + 2);**

Here **pbBuffer** is a pointer to unsigned char array.

calling function was,

```
i2c_receiveData(psDevice, prgDataRecv, &unRegLen);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, it appears the "frame length" is stored at offset 1 into the passed buffer.

It also appears that it is a 16-bit integer.

In order to get a usable 16-bit integer you must unpack from the buffer. It would be better to cast and use `htons`/`ntohs` instead, but I presume the architecture is well-known and portability isn't a concern.

For an input of, say, `pbBuffer = {0, 1, 2}`, this ends up being:

```
(1 << 8) | 2;
```

... which gives:

```
(00000001b << 8) | 00000010b
```

... shifting `1b` left 8 bits gives:

```
100000000b
```

... and OR-ing with `10b`:

```
100000010b
```

Now you have a 16-bit integer from the two 8-bit integers in `pbBuffer[1..2]`:

```
100000010b = 0x102
```

Comment: this means the frame length is 258?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, the frame length is sent in the protocol in the 2nd and 3rd byte. That expression builds the 16-bit integer from the 2 bytes.

`*(pbBuffer+x)` is the same as `pbBuffer[x]`, so the byte #1 is left-shifted by 8 and the byte #2 is added to it.

If you receive in your `pbBuffer`, e.g. `{ 0000 0000, 0101 0101, 1100 1100, ...}` (binary), the two bytes extracted will be

```
*(pbBuffer+1) = 0101 0101
*(pbBuffer+2) = 1100 1100
```

The calculation will be

```
 *(pbBuffer+1) << 8                  = 0101 0101 0000 0000
(*(pbBuffer+1) << 8) | *(pbBuffer+2) = 0101 0101 1100 1100
```

The bit-wise or (`|`) is the same as an addition here because the 8 lower bits of `(*(pbBuffer+1) << 8)` are all 0.

Note that the details depend a bit on the platform.

Comment: thanks allot for your detailed answer. above columnwise bits helped me understanding very well thanks

Answer (score 1):

Break the statement apart into smaller pieces:

```
 *(pbBuffer+1)       /* gets the byte_t value one beyond the pbBuffer pointer */
(*(pbBuffer+1) << 8) /* shifts that byte eight bits left -- in essence
                        xxxxxxxx00000000 -- where xxx comes from pbBuffer+1 */


*(pbBuffer+2)        /* gets the byte_t value two beyond the pbBuffer pointer */

(*(pbBuffer+1) << 8) | *(pbBuffer + 2)
/* xxxxxxxx00000000  |  yyyyyyyy */
   xxxxxxxxyyyyyyyy */
```

This reconstructs the two bytes specified into a single 16-bit data type. These
sorts of operations are especially common when dealing with networking
code, because different machines have different [byte
orders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order). The different orders mean numbers larger than one byte can't be
easily passed around on networks without use of a [network byte order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_byte_order#Endianness_in_networking)
to serve as an intermediary format. (Some computers work in network byte
order natively while others must perform conversions all the time.)